# Error in running startNetworkServer

Tags: java, api, netbeans, derby

I am trying to start the network server from outside netbeans. I did set the DERBY_INSTALL variable to the appropriate directory, then i issue setNetworkServerCP command which also works fine. But when **i try to run startNetworkServer i am getting the following error**.

> C:\Users\tandons>D:
>
> D:>cd D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>setNetworkServerCP DERBY_HOME or
>   DERBY_INSTALL not set. Set one of these variables to the location of
>   your Derby installation. D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>set
>   DERBY_INSTALL=D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2 .1\javadb
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>setNetworkServerCP.bat
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>SET
>   DERBY_INSTALL=D:\netbeans\GLASSF~1.1\j avadb
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>set
>   CLASSPATH=D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\j
>   avadb\lib\derbynet.jar;D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\lib\derbytools.jar;
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>setNetworkServerCP
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>SET
>   DERBY_INSTALL=D:\netbeans\GLASSF~1.1\j avadb
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>set
>   CLASSPATH=D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\j
>   avadb\lib\derbynet.jar;D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\lib\derbytools.jar;D:\n
>   etbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\lib\derbynet.jar;D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb
>   \lib\derbytools.jar;
>
> **D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>startNetworkServer Security
>   manager installed using the Basic server security policy. access
>   denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission"  "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
>           at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Unknown Sourc
>   e)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocke
>   t(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknow
>   n Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Sou
>   rce)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unk
>   nown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unkno
>   wn Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)**
>
> D:\netbeans\glassfish-v2.1\javadb\bin>

also is there a better way to do this from within a java program. I read the official doc given on Apache website( using NetworkServerControl api ) but i can make hardly anything out of whats given there..........

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. Workarounds are described in the links below. (Google is your friend):

[Netbeans bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239962)

[Blog 1](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/oracle-sun-jdk-7-derby-server-java-db-does-not-start-using-glassfish-3-1-2-in-netbeans-7-1-2-permission-denied/)

[Blog 2](http://stuetzpunkt.wordpress.com/2014/01/20/javadb-derbydb-access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-localhost1527-listenresolve/)

Comment: i am not sure if this is my problem....i tried to connect to the javaDB from within the netbeans environment in embedded mode and it was working fine...somehow when netbeans is setting the classpath variables it is working well but outside netbeans it won't....

Comment: also if you know can you please explain how the NetworkServerControl api is working...i feel using the programming approch would be much better....../